# Creating a new List out of a List but without dublicate items?

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, if-statement

i have a List

```
carner_list = ['<a href="/lyric/34808442/Loyle+Carner/Damselfly">Damselfly</a>',
 '<a href="/lyric/37311114/Loyle+Carner/Damselfly">Damselfly</a>',
 '<a href="/lyric/37360958/Loyle+Carner/Damselfly">Damselfly</a>',
 '<a href="/lyric/33661937/Loyle+Carner/The+Isle+of+Arran">The Isle of Arran</a>',
 '<a href="/lyric/33661936/Loyle+Carner/Mean+It+in+the+Morning">Mean It in the Morning</a>']
```

Now i want to get rid of the dublicated items. The Problem is, the items that are double are only different from each other at a specific point in the string, i[38:].

My idea was to create a for loop:

```
new_list = []
for i in carner_list:
       if i[38:] in new_list:
           print("found")
       else:
           new_list = new_list + [i]
           print("not")
```

But this is not working.

Is something in the syntax wrong or am i completely on the wrong track?

Best Russell

Comment: Do you need item with unique text? `Damselfly`, `The Isle of Arran`?

Comment: What output is wrong with your current code?

Comment: when you check whether the items from `carner_list` are also in `new_list`, this will always evaluate to `False`, because `new_list` is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typed a small function called `listContains` that I think can solve your problem. Your code is not working because you search for the value `i[38:]` in your `new_list`, when in `new_list` you append the entire value of `i`. 
So you should also applied the rule of *[38:]* on each value of the list. 
I think the code below can explain better what I'm saying:

```
carner_list = ['<a href="/lyric/34808442/Loyle+Carner/Damselfly">Damselfly</a>',
 '<a href="/lyric/37311114/Loyle+Carner/Damselfly">Damselfly</a>',
 '<a href="/lyric/37360958/Loyle+Carner/Damselfly">Damselfly</a>',
 '<a href="/lyric/33661937/Loyle+Carner/The+Isle+of+Arran">The Isle of Arran</a>',
 '<a href="/lyric/33661936/Loyle+Carner/Mean+It+in+the+Morning">Mean It in the Morning</a>']
new_list = []

def listContains(myList, toSearch):
  for val in myList:
    if val[38:] == toSearch:
      return True
  return False

for i in carner_list:
  if listContains(new_list, i[38:]):
    print("found")
  else:
    new_list.append(i)
    print("not")
print(new_list)
```

If you want to test it you can do it from [here](https://repl.it/repls/ConventionalAdmiredType#main.py)

Comment: thx a lot Giovanni. This was exactly the problem. Could solve it.

Comment: I'm glad it solved your problem please chose my answer as your solution so also future users can use it instantly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The portion of the strings (from index 38 to the end) with which you use to determine duplication is not what you actually store in the list, so the `in` operator won't work.

You can instead use a dict to store the de-duplicated strings, with the portion of the strings you care about as the key, so that the `in` operator can work:

```
new = {}
for i in carner_list:
    key = i[38:]
    if key not in new:
        new[key] = i
print(list(new.values()))
```

This outputs:

```
['<a href="/lyric/34808442/Loyle+Carner/Damselfly">Damselfly</a>', '<a href="/lyric/33661937/Loyle+Carner/The+Isle+of+Arran">The Isle of Arran</a>', '<a href="/lyric/33661936/Loyle+Carner/Mean+It+in+the+Morning">Mean It in the Morning</a>']
```

Answer (score 1):

So the way you are currently searching, you are looking if the sub string is equal to anything in the new_list. This will never be true since it's a sub string.

You can use a lambda and then filter it for true results to see if the item is in the new list. Then cast it to a list and check if that list has a length not equal to 0.

```
len(list(filter(lambda x: i[38:] in x, new_list))) != 0
```

***Final Code***

```
carner_list = ['<a href="/lyric/34808442/Loyle+Carner/Damselfly">Damselfly</a>',
 '<a href="/lyric/37311114/Loyle+Carner/Damselfly">Damselfly</a>',
 '<a href="/lyric/37360958/Loyle+Carner/Damselfly">Damselfly</a>',
 '<a href="/lyric/33661937/Loyle+Carner/The+Isle+of+Arran">The Isle of Arran</a>',
 '<a href="/lyric/33661936/Loyle+Carner/Mean+It+in+the+Morning">Mean It in the Morning</a>']


new_list = []

for i in carner_list:
    if len(list(filter(lambda x: i[38:] in x, new_list))) != 0:
        print("found")
    else:
        new_list.append(i)
        print("not")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `BeautifulSoup` to parse the html and then check

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

carner_list = ['<a href="/lyric/34808442/Loyle+Carner/Damselfly">Damselfly</a>',
 '<a href="/lyric/37311114/Loyle+Carner/Damselfly">Damselfly</a>',
 '<a href="/lyric/37360958/Loyle+Carner/Damselfly">Damselfly</a>',
 '<a href="/lyric/33661937/Loyle+Carner/The+Isle+of+Arran">The Isle of Arran</a>',
 '<a href="/lyric/33661936/Loyle+Carner/Mean+It+in+the+Morning">Mean It in the Morning</a>']

new_list = []
check_val = set()
for i in carner_list:
    s = BeautifulSoup(i, "html.parser")
    if s.text not in check_val:    #check for text
        new_list.append(i)
        check_val.add(s.text)
print(new_list)
```

**Output:**

```
['<a href="/lyric/34808442/Loyle+Carner/Damselfly">Damselfly</a>',
 '<a href="/lyric/33661937/Loyle+Carner/The+Isle+of+Arran">The Isle of '
 'Arran</a>',
 '<a href="/lyric/33661936/Loyle+Carner/Mean+It+in+the+Morning">Mean It in the '
 'Morning</a>']
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use regular expressions

```
import re
carner_list = ['<a href="/lyric/34808442/Loyle+Carner/Damselfly">Damselfly</a>',
 '<a href="/lyric/37311114/Loyle+Carner/Damselfly">Damselfly</a>',
 '<a href="/lyric/37360958/Loyle+Carner/Damselfly">Damselfly</a>',
 '<a href="/lyric/33661937/Loyle+Carner/The+Isle+of+Arran">The Isle of Arran</a>',
 '<a href="/lyric/33661936/Loyle+Carner/Mean+It+in+the+Morning">Mean It in the Morning</a>']

print({re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"', x)[0].split("/")[4]: x for x in carner_list })

#Below is the output generated 
'''
{'Damselfly': '<a href="/lyric/37360958/Loyle+Carner/Damselfly">Damselfly</a>', 'The+Isle+of+Arran': '<a href="/lyric/33661937/Loyle+Carner/The+Isle+of+Arran">The Isle of Arran</a>', 'Mean+It+in+the+Morning': '<a href="/lyric/33661936/Loyle+Carner/Mean+It+in+the+Morning">Mean It in the Morning</a>'}
'''
```